# Mobile Browser Automation to interact with a website

Tags: android, flutter, selenium, webbrowser-control

I try to set up a new app, that will need to interact with a website to fill a form. For windows, no problem, I use selenium java code to insert it, but I don't know what should I use for mobile. The website that hosts the form don't have an api, and they potentially want to block requests like this.

I tried appium or selenium server, but it's not what I want, since I don't want a big infrastructure, I want every devices to be able to send its own requests.

My app is written in flutter, but I'm open to any other solution.

Thank for the help

Comment: want to load a webview in a mobile application?

Comment: yes, and I want to be able to click or send keys to webElement